# rails 5 param is missing or the value is empty: phone_number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the devise gem and I used it to create a basic User model. Afterwards, I added a "phone_number" field to it and I want to be able to edit that phone_number field in another controller. The way I have set up that controller's form to edit the Phone number is like this:

Dashboard controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  # So that we don't have to authenticate users for only the home action in this controller
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:home]

  def home
    current_user.update(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to current_user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to current_user, notice: 'Errors.' }
      end
    end

  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:phone_number)
  end
end
```

And my form is:

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :phone_number %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :phone_number, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

Right now, this home method of this controller is routed for my root page (so as soon as you hit localhost:3000, it will access this home controller.

Unfortunately, the page isn't even loading and the error on load I am getting is:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in DashboardController#home
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: user

How can I set up a form in my Dashboard controller to let the current_user edit their phone number field? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the logs.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to `localhost:3000` you're not supplying any params, but your controller expects params[:user]:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:phone_number)
  end
```

That's why you get the errors. You probably don't want to route your root to this `#home` action.